# Launchpad design not load after upgrade from Sitecore 8.0

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

[image: Sitecore 8.1 launchpad]

Sitecore 8.1 Launchpad not as design after upgrade from 8.0 to 8.1.Anyone idea how to resolved it. 
When i refresh the page then i am getting following error in log.

> ERROR Cannot load icon file
>   'temp/IconCache/People/48x48/astrologer.png'. Zip archive
>   '/sitecore/shell/themes/standard/temp.zip' with icons not found

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems you client folder in sitecore content tree inside core database could not upgrade properly. 
To solve the issue, either upgrade again by giving proper permission on website folder or install a fresh sitecore 8.1 instance, from here create a package for client folder in content tree FROM CORE database and install in your upgraded instance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the fact that the upgrade from Sitecore 8.0 to 8.1 has not been executed properly.

My assumption here is that files found at`website/sitecore/shell/client` has not been updated properly.

Possible solution:

1. Perform the upgrade again but this seems to me not an option because you already performed the upgrade.
2. Install a fresh Sitecore 8.1 instance and migrate your code, configs and items to the new instance.
3. Copy the files from the `website/sitecore/shell/client` folder of a fresh Sitecore8.1 instance to the upgraded one.

My recommendation would be to choose option 2 since if the upgrade has not been done properly, there might be other issues such as config files or items that have not been upgraded properly.

Moreover, I've seen that upgrade tends to cause to much trouble as configs and dlls are not upgraded properly or redundant configs are not removed. So, this is why option 2 is more viable.

The error you are seeing is that, Sitecore stored icons in the MediaCache folder found at `website/App_Data/`. This is another fact that the upgrade has not been done properly